# How to deploy to BlueMix: 404 Error

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, hyperledger

I am a first time Bluemix user. When I clicked the "Deploy to BlueMix" button, I got the following error:

> Downloading artifacts...DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFUL Target:
>   https://api.ng.bluemix.net Creating service instance myblockchain in
>   org DIGITIVELY / space dev as ngzhongcai@digitively.com... FAILED
>   Server error, status code: 502, error code: 10001, message: Service
>   broker error: {"description"=>"Error 404 received from broker url
>   https://obc-service-broker-prod.mybluemix.net/v2/service_instances/f4685ca8-682b-4a10-b239-856d292e10d1?accepts_incomplete=true"}
>
> Finished: FAILED
>
> Stage has no runtime information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same error. It seems blockchain service is down. http://status.w3.bluemix.net/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Above link worked for me. All 3 regions down.